# Using Cargo, how can I add a system library to the link command?

Tags: rust, ffi, rust-cargo

I'm trying to call into a standard C library (libstatgrab) on my system, and can't figure out how to get the library included in the link line.

I've got Cargo running a `build.rs` , and the output from that is:

```
cargo:rustc-link-lib=statgrab
cargo:rustc-link-search=native=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Since my example is a small prototype, here are all of the files involved:

`src/systemstats.rs`

```
extern crate libc;

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct sg_load_stats {
    min1: libc::c_double,
    min5: libc::c_double,
    min15: libc::c_double,
    systime: libc::time_t,
}

extern "C" {
    fn sg_get_load_stats() -> *mut sg_load_stats;
}


fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let load_stats = sg_get_load_stats();
        println!("[load_stats] {:?}", *load_stats);
    }
}
```

`Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "palimpsest"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Savanni D'Gerinel <savanni@luminescent-dreams.com>"]
build = "build.rs"

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2.43"

[[bin]]
name = "systemstats"
path = "src/systemstats.rs"
```

`build.rs`

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=statgrab");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/");
}
```

And, finally, the build output:

```
root@0a2938cbf3b7:/src/palimpsest# cargo build
   Compiling palimpsest v0.1.0 (file:///src/palimpsest)
   Compiling libc v0.2.43
ls -l error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-m64" "-L" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "/src/palimpsest/target/debug/deps/systemstats-a71368fbbfd6ba9e.1y16o1qfye96o7m0.rcgu.o" "/src/palimpsest/target/debug/deps/systemstats-a71368fbbfd6ba9e.3ewjf7fna93e7dd4.rcgu.o" "/src/palimpsest/target/debug/deps/systemstats-a71368fbbfd6ba9e.3rngp6bm2u2q5z0y.rcgu.o" "/src/palimpsest/target/debug/deps/systemstats-a71368fbbfd6ba9e.4oc10dk278mpk1vy.rcgu.o" "/src/palimpsest/target/debug/deps/systemstats-a71368fbbfd6ba9e.4xq48u46a1pwiqn7.rcgu.o" "/src/palimpsest/target/debug/deps/systemstats-a71368fbbfd6ba9e.51s1w397y42gpez1.rcgu.o" "/src/palimpsest/target/debug/deps/systemstats-a71368fbbfd6ba9e.8xzrsc1ux72v29j.rcgu.o" "/src/palimpsest/target/debug/deps/systemstats-a71368fbbfd6ba9e.oa3rad818d8sgn4.rcgu.o" "-o" "/src/palimpsest/target/debug/deps/systemstats-a71368fbbfd6ba9e" "/src/palimpsest/target/debug/deps/systemstats-a71368fbbfd6ba9e.crate.allocator.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro" "-Wl,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/src/palimpsest/target/debug/deps" "-L" "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" "-L" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/src/palimpsest/target/debug/deps/liblibc-fe86c4c07bd339cb.rlib" "-Wl,--start-group" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-448e7f800092c158.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-187d239173779b21.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc_jemalloc-1016cb92bf3e0c0f.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-404ca41e10f51fe1.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc_system-3c640c2d04fa8073.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-6ea835c502ac484a.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-b77d79244be470bc.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-a51c1c47035430ae.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-0413689b51de5d7d.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lutil" "-lutil" "-ldl" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lpthread" "-lgcc_s" "-lc" "-lm" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lutil" "-lutil"
  = note: /src/palimpsest/target/debug/deps/systemstats-a71368fbbfd6ba9e.3ewjf7fna93e7dd4.rcgu.o: In function `systemstats::main':
          /src/palimpsest/src/systemstats.rs:19: undefined reference to `sg_get_load_stats'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


error: aborting due to previous error
```

The build output is a pain to read, but where I see `"-L" "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"` in it, I do not see `-lstatgrab`. My understanding of the documents was that `cargo:rustc-link-lib=statgrab` should have added that flag, but it doesn't.

Frustratingly, I've done some work linking to Cocoa on MacOS, and the only think I needed for that was a single line in my source: `#[link(name = "Cocoa", kind = "framework")]`, and so I don't understand why I can't just use a similar line, `#[link(name = "statgrab", kind = "dylib")]` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I don't need `build.rs` at all. Or perhaps I would if the library were installed in a non-standard location. However, I can now successfully link and run the application.

First, I removed `build = "build.rs"` from Cargo.toml.

Second, I went back into my code and moved the `#[link(name = "statgrab", kind = "dylib")]` to right before the `extern "C"` stanza.

`systemstats.rs`

```
extern crate libc;

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct sg_load_stats {
    min1: libc::c_double,
    min5: libc::c_double,
    min15: libc::c_double,
    systime: libc::time_t,
}

#[link(name = "statgrab", kind = "dylib")]
extern "C" {
    fn sg_init(ignore_errors: libc::c_int) -> libc::c_int;
    fn sg_get_load_stats() -> *mut sg_load_stats;
}


fn main() {
    unsafe {
        sg_init(1);
        let load_stats = sg_get_load_stats();
        println!("[load_stats] {:?}", *load_stats);
    }
}
```

And then the output:

```
root@040ee947460c:/src/palimpsest# cargo run
   Compiling palimpsest v0.1.0 (file:///src/palimpsest)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.54s
     Running `target/debug/systemstats`
[load_stats] sg_load_stats { min1: 0.09, min5: 0.05, min15: 0.01, systime: 1540037934 }
root@040ee947460c:/src/palimpsest#
```

Comment: Sorry, but where's the crash? I see only the output specified in `main`.

Comment: Sorry, that's in a previous version of the text. I will remove that line now that I have the whole thing working. Crash was unrelated to the problem at hand, and was simply that `sg_init` is necessary before anything else.